# Regex, comma and space handling

Tags: c#, regex

I require the following

- Remove multiple spaces (replace with 1)
- Remove multiple commas (replace with 1)
- Trim all commas and spaces from the start and end
- Remove all spaces preceding a comma
- Always have 1 space after a comma
- Always have only 1 comma and space together

Put simply, this is just a basic sentence tidy (in regards to commas and spaces).

The current solution I have is working, though I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce seemingly redundant steps with smarter "regex" expressions

**Current solution**

```
[TestCase(" , aaa,bbb ,, , ccc, ddd,,  eee   fff , , ggg , hhh ,", ExpectedResult = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee fff, ggg, hhh")]
[TestCase(",, aaa,bbb ,, , ccc, ddd,,  eee   fff , , ggg , hhh ,, ", ExpectedResult = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee fff, ggg, hhh")]
[TestCase(",,  ,,", ExpectedResult = "")]
public string CleanSentence(string source)
{
   var duplicateSpaces = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);
   var spacesBeforeCommas = new Regex(@"\s+(?=,)", RegexOptions.None);
   var duplicateCommas = new Regex(@"[,]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);
   var loneComma = new Regex(@",(?=[^\s])", RegexOptions.None);
   var multiCommaAndSpace = new Regex(@"(, ){2,}", RegexOptions.None);

   source = duplicateSpaces.Replace(source, " ");
   source = duplicateCommas.Replace(source, ",");
   source = spacesBeforeCommas.Replace(source, "");
   source = loneComma.Replace(source, ", ");
   source = multiCommaAndSpace.Replace(source, ", ");

   //Trim the crud 
   source = source.Trim(',', ' ');

   return source;
}
```

**Test cases**

```
var test1 = " , aaa,bbb ,, , ccc, ddd,,  eee   fff , , ggg , hhh ," 
var test2 = ",, aaa,bbb ,, , ccc, ddd,,  eee   fff , , ggg , hhh ,, " 
var test3 = ",,  ,,"
```

**Intended results**

```
var Result1 = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee fff, ggg, hhh" 
var Result2 = "aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee fff, ggg, hhh" 
var Result3 = ""
```

Though I'm wondering if there is a way to remove a couple of redundant steps.

**Note**: this is a quantifiable question, namely to reduce the steps involved with smarter regex expressions.

Comment: If it's working, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have another solution just by using only `string` built-in function and a little `Regex.Replace`.

```
public string CleanString(string rawString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawString)) return rawString;

    rawString = Regex.Replace(rawString, @"\s+", " ");
    rawString = Regex.Replace(rawString, @"(?<=,)\s+|\s+(?=,)", "");
    return string.Join(", ", rawString.Trim().Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Trim();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks John, this looks great!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Reduce the number of spaces before a word: `\s+\b` with `\s`
2. Take care of your lone commas.
3. Single out the remaining commas: `[,\s]*,` with `,`

This will also remove spaces at the end of each string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it down to with some inspiration from *John Woo*

```
 source = Regex.Replace(source, "[ ]{2,}", " ");
 source = Regex.Replace(source, "[, ]*,[, ]*", ", ");
 return source.Trim(',', ' ');
```

- Remove double spaces
- Remove all comma and space where there is a least 1 comma
- and the Trim to take care of start and finish

Answer (score 0):

Seems like just splitting by space and comma should be enough:

```
public string CleanSentence(string source)
{
   return string.Join(", ", (source ?? "").Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slai, ill run it through the tests